# How to interpret the regular expression 0*10|01(01)*?

Tags: regular-expressions

I'm having some trouble understanding the regular expression $0^*10|01(01)^*$.
The expression matches strings like $00010$. But for some reason, I wasn't able to find a string that matches the $(01)^*$ at the end. An equivalent expression with capturing groups to demonstrate the order of evaluation would be very much helpful.

Comment: 0101 matches the second part of the expressions.

Comment: The language corresponding to a regular expression is described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory).

Comment: @Steven when I tried the string 0101 with the online tool [regextester](https://www.regextester.com), it returned a match only for the first three characters, i.e., 010 and the 1 at the end doesn't seem to match.

Comment: 010 also matches your re, that why the tool you're using reports that match.

Comment: The evaluation is (0*(10))|((01)(01)*), so one of $00\cdots10$ or $0101\cdots01$.

Answer (score 1):

For a regular expression $r$, the regular expression $r^*$ matches all words of the form $w_1 \ldots w_n$, where $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ are matched by $r$ (possibly $n = 0$). For example $01$ matches only the word $01$, and so $(01)^*$ matches the words $\epsilon, 01, 0101, 010101, \dots$